# How to build a histogram of numpy 2 dimensional array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

I have a 256x256 matrix of values and I would like to plot a histogram of these values

If I am not mistaken, the histogram must be calculated in a vector of values, correct? so here is what I have tried:

```
from skimage.measure import compare_ssim
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

d = np.load("BB_Digital.npy")

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x=d.ravel(), color='#0504aa', bins='auto', alpha=0.7, rwidth=0.85)

plt.grid(axis='y', alpha=0.75)
plt.xlabel('Value')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.title('Blue channel Co-occurency matrix')
maxfreq = n.max()

# Set a clean upper y-axis limit.
plt.ylim(ymax=np.ceil(maxfreq / 10) * 10 if maxfreq % 10 else maxfreq + 10)
plt.show()
```

But then, I have a very strange result:

[image: Vectorized matrix result]

When I don't use the ravel function (use the 2D matrix) the following result is shown:

[image: Histogram of 2D matrix]

However, both histograms seem to be wrong, as I verified later:

```
>>> np.count_nonzero(d==0)
51227
>>> np.count_nonzero(d==1)
2529
>>> np.count_nonzero(d==2)
1275
>>> np.count_nonzero(d==3)
885
>>> np.count_nonzero(d==4)
619
>>> np.count_nonzero(d==5)
490
>>> np.count_nonzero(d==6)
403
>>> np.max(d)
12518
>>> np.min(d)
0
```

How can I build a correct histogram?

**P.s: [Here is the file](https://www.ic.unicamp.br/%7Era023169/BB_Digital.npy) if you could help me.**

Comment: @Xbel the same result. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Xbel it's just your data is too skewed. You have too many zeros in your data.

Comment: @Xbel even that way the histogram seems to be wrong, I don't have 60000 zero values :-(

Comment: You have 51k zeros. Remove the zero, your data is still skewed with 2.5k `1`'s, 1.28k `2`'s and so on. Btw, it looks like you are working with an image. You should also consider `cv2`.

Comment: @QuangHoang thanks, it is a co-occurency matrix, is there any way to plot its histogram or something using cv2?

Comment: Use log scale on both axis. But I think you better do a `plt.imshow` with colorbar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data seems to be discrete. Setting explicit bin boundaries at the halves could show the frequency of each value. As there are very high but infrequent values, the following example cuts off at 50:

```py
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

d = np.load("BB_Digital.npy")

plt.hist(d.ravel(), bins=np.arange(-0.5, 51),  color='#0504aa', alpha=0.7, rwidth=0.85)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.margins(x=0.02)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Another visualization could show a `pcolormesh` where the colors use a logarithmic scale. As the values start at 0, adding 1 avoids minus infinity:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
import numpy as np

d = np.load("BB_Digital.npy")
plt.pcolormesh(d + 1, norm=LogNorm(), cmap='inferno')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image: pcolormesh]

Yet another visualization concentrates on the diagonal values:

```py
plt.plot(np.diagonal(d), color='navy')
ind_max = np.argmax(np.diagonal(d))
plt.vlines(ind_max, 0, d[ind_max, ind_max], colors='crimson', ls=':')
plt.yscale('log')
```

[image: values on diagonal]